# Returning Struct from Class

Tags: c#, struct, return

So I am trying to call a function in another class called DMLib. If I were to return a List of structs, how can I properly bring that back into my main. For example:

**Struct:**

```
    public struct folder
    {
        public int FID;
        public string Name;
        public int Type;
        public int TotalMessages;
    }
```

**Class member decleration:**

```
public List<folder> getFolders(string sessionKey)
```

**Class member call from main.cs:**

```
List<folder> folders = new List<folder>();
folders = (List<folder>)DMLib.getFolders(sessionkey);
```

**Error:**

[image: Error]

This error says that my List of struct folder that is defined in my main.cs can not be converted into the List of struct folder from my class. How can I make this conversion happen?

Comment: Where is this struct defined?  You have a scoping issue.

Comment: Are the `folder` types actually the same type? Or are they two different structs called `folder`? You cannot tell from the error message since the full type name is obscured.

Comment: The struct is defined in both the main.cs and my class/

Comment: They are two different structs but defined the same way, but defined in two different files.

Comment: If they are different types then you will need to convert between them.

Comment: If they are exactly the same why have two?

Comment: I couldn't get it to reference correctly before.

Comment: That type most certainly shouldn't be a `struct` in the first place.  It's mutable, doesn't represent a logical value, and is larger than a struct should be.  It should be a `class`.

Comment: Ok I will make note of that. Is there any difficulty returning classes though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the declaration of the `folder` Type to be fully qualified to include the namespace, or declare `using` aliases at the top, for each of the namespaces that the two `folder` types reside in, and use the alias in your code.